# Draw an arc over 360 degrees

Tags: tikz-pgf, arc

I have the following problem with tikz: I want to draw some circular arcs, but unfortunately these arcs have degrees which pass the 360° line. I would like to be able to draw these arcs with one single command, but I can't figure out how to do it. If I give the arc commands two angles where the first is larger than the second, tikz will simply interchange the angles before drawing them.

```
% radius, two angles, node attribute/name
\newcommand{\drawarc}[5]
{
\draw[gray, very thin] (0,0) --  (#2:#1);
\draw (#2:#1) arc(#2:#3:#1);
\draw[gray, very thin] (0,0) --  (#3:#1);
\draw({(#2+#3)/2}:#1) node[#4] {#5};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]

\drawarc{1cm}{80}{100}{above}{1};

\drawarc{0.9cm}{60}{110}{below}{2};

\drawarc{0.75cm}{20}{85}{below left}{4};

\drawarc{0.8cm}{95}{150}{below right}{3};

\drawarc{1cm}{105}{200}{above}{5};

% I would like to replace these 2 commands
% by one, drawing an arc from 195 to 75 degrees
\drawarc{1.2cm}{195}{360}{above}{6};
\drawarc{1.2cm}{0}{75}{}{};

\drawarc{1.3cm}{160}{280}{left}{8};

\drawarc{0.9cm}{140}{190}{right}{7};

% and the same here
\drawarc{1cm}{260}{360}{above left}{9};
\drawarc{1cm}{0}{40}{}{};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I am bounding every arc by lines from/to (0,0), so if I draw multiple arcs where I only need one, the additional lines look somewhat crappy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use angles greater than 360!

Replace your 4 lines with the following two:

```
 \drawarc{1.2cm}{195}{435}{above}{6}; 
%\drawarc{1.2cm}{0}{75}{}{}; 360+75=435
```

and

```
  \drawarc{1cm}{260}{400}{above left}{9}; 
%\drawarc{1cm}{0}{40}{}{}; 360+40=400
```

to get the desired result:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

To do what you want, you can use the `delta angle` option for an arc. What you have to write is

```
\draw (195:1.2) arc[radius=1.2,start angle=195,delta angle=240]
```

If you want to go the other way, use -240 and not 240.

OR

using Yossi's solution, `end angle = 435`.

Answer (score 5):

Damn, away half an hour, and suddenly there are three answers. Anyway, here's mine:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}

% radius, two angles, node attribute/name
\newcommand{\drawarc}[5]{%
\ifthenelse{#3>#2}%
% if second anvle is bigger, then as usual
           {\draw (#2:#1) arc(#2:#3:#1);
            \draw({(#2+#3)/2}:#1) node[#4] {#5};}%
% otherwise, draw two arcs, and also adapt the node position;
% colors are just for illustration, just remove the [red] and [blue]
           {\draw[red] (#2:#1) arc(#2:360:#1);
            \draw[blue] (360:#1) arc(0:#3:#1);
            \draw({(#2+#3)/2+180}:#1) node[#4] {#5};}%
% connections to arc ends, un changed            
\draw[gray, very thin] (0,0) --  (#2:#1);%
\draw[gray, very thin] (0,0) --  (#3:#1);%

}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]

% old "solution
\drawarc{1.2cm}{195}{360}{above}{6};
\drawarc{1.2cm}{0}{75}{right}{7};

% new example
\drawarc{1.7cm}{195}{75}{below}{8};

% free bonus pacman!
\drawarc{2.7cm}{225}{135}{right}{Waka Waka!};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of defining your command in that way I would do the following. Not only will it automatically do it the right way, from your defined angles, but it will also make the middle connection more *pretty*.

```
\newcommand{\drawarc}[5]{
    \ifnum#3<#2
      \draw (#2:#1) arc(#2:360:#1) arc(0:#3:#1);
      \node[#4] at ({(#2+360+#3)/2}:#1) {#5};
    \else
      \draw (#2:#1) arc(#2:#3:#1);
      \node[#4] at ({(#2+#3)/2}:#1) {#5};
    \fi
    \draw[gray, very thin,rounded corners=.1pt] (#3:#1) -- (0,0) --  (#2:#1);
}
```

I have changed the way you place your node. This is more clean, at least I think. Further notice the `rounded corners` which makes the center piece look ***much*** better.

[image]